# Google equivalent to Yahoo Placemaker

Tags: api, google-maps, gis, yahoo-maps

Does Google has a service similar to Yahoo! Placemaker:

1. Developers specify structured and unstructured content; feeds, web pages, news, status articles, etc.
2. Placemaker identifies, disambiguates and extracts places
3. Placemaker returns geographic metadata, which determines the whereness of structured and unstructured content

?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think so, and I would be scared when it happens. Skynet won't be far off.. ;)

It sounds very similar to Reuters OpenCalais: http://www.opencalais.com/

Answer (score 2):

PlaceMaker became [PlaceSpotter](http://www.ysearchblog.com/2012/09/26/boss-geo/) in 2012. The Yahoo! BOSS APIs (including PlaceSpotter) are [shutting down](https://developer.yahoo.com/boss/placespotter/) on March 31, 2016. If you're looking for a replacement or alternative, you should check out the open source project [CLAVIN](https://github.com/Berico-Technologies/CLAVIN) or the recently-launched [Geoparser.io API](https://geoparser.io/).

Answer (score 0):

No they don't have it.